# Incorrect Command (INSERT INTO ... SELECT with GROUP BY)

Tags: sql

The exercise for my online course is as follows

This time, the university needs a list of average results of written and oral exams in each subject (from the exam table).

The new table, report_average_scores consists of the following columns: subject, avg_written_exam_score, and avg_oral_exam_score (which are of type DECIMAL(4,2)).

Help the university insert data into the report_average_scores table.

I have attempted adding the GROUP BY as I should, but I am unable to pass the section. Also, I can not find where the decimal would play part.

```
INSERT INTO report_average_scores 
(
subject,
avg_written_exam_score,
avg_oral_exam_score
)
SELECT 
    subject,
    written_exam_score,
    oral_exam_score
FROM exam;
```

I expect the output to approve the code, but I am running into the same error.

Comment: Welcome, @whoisavxnue! What is the exact error you get?

Comment: The current error I am receiving is "Oops try again! Incorrect command."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I seeing it wrong or you just need to average?

```
SELECT 
    subject,
    AVG(written_exam_score),
    AVG(oral_exam_score)
FROM exam group by subject
```

Comment: That was all I needed to do. For some reason I did not notice that is all I needed. Thanks!